# BLAS, ATLAS, LAPACK Shared library minimal example

Tags: fortran, redhat, lapack, blas, atlas

I installed atlas, blas and lapack x86_64 packages via

```
yum install atlas.x86_64 blas.x86_64 lapack.x86_64
```

on a Redhat 6.6 (ii) distro which installs a shared library but am having problems compiling and linking. For example, if I try to compile the minimal working example:

```
program main
  print *, 'hello world'
end program main
```

using

```
gfortran -L. main.f90 -llapack -lblas -o main
```

the compiler doesn't find the libraries and I get the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm relatively new to fortran and linux so I'm probably missing something obvious. I'm lost hours on compiling the libraries from source unsuccessfully too.

Pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Which linux distribution you use? Centos, Fedora? Which version?

Comment: Try running `locate liblapack`. Did you install sttic or shared versions of the libraries?

Comment: @ctheo & @ Vladimir 

(i) I am using Redhat 6.6
(ii) The yum install created shared libraries (ideally I would like to compile static libraries but I run into similar difficulties with linking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `*-devel` versions of those packages.

E.g., with a virtual Fedora 17 system I had lying around:

```
$ cat main.f90
program main
  print *, 'hello world'
end program main
$ gfortran -L. main.f90 -llapack -lblas -o main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ sudo yum install atlas.x86_64 blas.x86_64 lapack.x86_64
...
Installed:
  blas.x86_64 0:3.4.2-2.fc17            lapack.x86_64 0:3.4.2-2.fc17           

Complete!
$ gfortran -L. main.f90 -llapack -lblas -o main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ sudo yum install atlas-devel.x86_64 blas-devel.x86_64 lapack-devel.x86_64
...
Installed:
  atlas-devel.x86_64 0:3.8.4-3.fc17       blas-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.2-2.fc17     
  lapack-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.2-2.fc17     

Complete!
$ gfortran -L. main.f90 -llapack -lblas -o main
(Success)
```