# Attempting to run R with Atlas/OpenBLAS on redhat

Tags: r, installation, redhat, atlas, openblas

For two days I've been trying to install Openblas/atlas with Lapack and use it in R. it's driving me crazy. I'm at a point where I can't even think anymore.

My server uses:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Here is what I've installed so far:

```
[root@tpdb05 atlas]# yum install atlas.x86_64 blas.x86_64 lapack.x86_64 Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
    Setting up Install Process
    Package atlas-3.8.4-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Package blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Package lapack-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
[root@tpdb05 ruser]#


yum install lapack.i686
    Installed:
    lapack.i686 0:3.2.1-4.el6

    Dependency Installed:
    blas.i686 0:3.2.1-4.el6                          glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.166.el6_7.3        libgfortran.i686 0:4.4.7-16.el6
    nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-23.el6_7

    Dependency Updated:
    glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.166.el6_7.3         glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.166.el6_7.3    glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.12-1.166.el6_7.3
    glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.166.el6_7.3 nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.14.3-23.el6_7


yum install atlas.i686
    Installed:
        atlas.i686 0:3.8.4-2.el6

[root@tpdb05 SRPMS]# yum install rpm-build
    Installed:
    rpm-build.x86_64 0:4.8.0-47.el6

    Dependency Installed:
    redhat-rpm-config.noarch 0:9.0.3-44.el6

    Dependency Updated:
    rpm.x86_64 0:4.8.0-47.el6             rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.8.0-47.el6             rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.8.0-47.el6

[root@tpdb05 SRPMS]# yum install atlas-c++-devel.x86_64
    Installed:
      atlas-c++-devel.x86_64 0:0.6.1-1.el5.rf

    Dependency Installed:
      atlas-c++.x86_64 0:0.6.1-1.el5.rf
```

several sources I've tried without success:
    [1](http://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-r-through-better-blas/) [2](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/#comment-769)  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057585/blas-atlas-lapack-shared-library-minimal-example)

[The R manual mentions the following:](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#ATLAS)

> The usual way to specify ATLAS will be via
>   --with-blas="-lf77blas -latlas"

However I have no clue where to use this command. While installing R? I'm pretty sure it should be possible to simply swap between libraries..

How do I get R to use the atlas/openblas/lapack libraries?

Comment: any help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984141/does-installing-blas-atlas-mkl-openblas-will-speed-up-r-package-that-is-written)?

Comment: @MichaelChirico It is definately a useful link, but unfortunately it doesn't tell me how to actually use the libraries :(

Comment: @MichaelChirico it looks like the gcbd package has an install option using apt-get. I'll try to convert those to yum commands :)

Comment: The R manual (from your link) says: "However, these have to be explicitly requested at configure time:" so my guess would be that you have to build R from source with these custom flags, but I might mis-read this.

Comment: Managed to get it working [using this guide](http://lostingeospace.blogspot.nl/2012/06/r-and-hpc-blas-mpi-in-linux-environment.html) but ended up using [Revolutionanalytics R version(RRO)](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/) for even better performance.